# Animate camera continuously cause maps bearing not smooth

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to rotate `MapView` via `sensor` changed value. But it did not as smooth as `Google Maps` application. Seem the `animate` methods called continuously causes the `maps` bearing does not smooth. It seems that the new `animateCamera` call will cancelled the previous one's `animation`, isn't it? What am I doing wrong in my code below? Can I improve my bearing performance?

```
    mSensorManager.setOnDeviceRotationListener(bearing -> {
                if (mCurrentLocation == null 
                     || Math.abs(mOldBearing - bearing) < ROTATION_THRESHOLD) { // atleast 5 degrees.
                    return;
                }
                mOldBearing = bearing;
                LatLng target =
                        new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
                CameraPosition oldCamera = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition();
                CameraPosition newCamera = CameraPosition.builder()
                        .zoom(Math.max(oldCamera.zoom, DEFAULT_MAP_COMPASS_ZOOM))
                        .target(target)
                        .tilt(DEFAULT_MAP_TILT)
                        .bearing(bearing)
                        .build();
                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(newCamera));
            }
```